# NSUserAutomatorTask executeWithInput result always empty

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am on macOS 10.14, objective-c, X-Code 10.3
The app is sandboxed.

I want my app to be able to run Automator workflows. Running them works, passing input and variables to them works, receiving a result does not work.

I advice my users to put their workflow in the aplications scripts folder.

Then i call the workflow like so:

```
NSError* err = nil;
NSUserAutomatorTask * task = [[NSUserAutomatorTask alloc] initWithURL:urlToWorkflow error:nil];

task.variables=attributes; // NSDictionary with additional variables
[task executeWithInput:@[@"TEST",@"TEST2"] completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error){

    NSLog(@"Result: %@",result);
    if(error)
        NSLog(@"Error while executing workflow %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

My test workflow has only one item (Choose from list). The list with the two choices "TEST" and "TEST2" is presented properly. But my selection is not returned to the completion handlers "result" variable. I tried it with different worflow items. Input works, output not.

```
 // Log
 Result: (
 )
```

According to Apple Docs it should.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I can confirm the issue, but have no idea about the cause or any solution. You might want to file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I filed a bug report with Apple.